# Maven archetype: Boolean properties

Tags: java, maven, maven-archetype

Can I implement the following in a Maven archetype:

If a certain property is set to true, then a package should be generated (otherwise not).

Answer (score 1):

Maven Archetype allows you to execute groovy script after generation. Check [Post-generation script](https://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/advanced-usage.html) section.

- Generate you classes as following:

```
    #if ( $doGenerate )
    // your content here
    #else
    *DELETE*
    #end
```

- Create simple script which go through all the files and delete some if it content has *DELETE* marker.